# Simple Matlab interpolation. Want to avoid interp2 or interp3

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a three-dimensional matrix of dimensions ZxXxY, which I have reduced to two dimensions (size Zx(XxY). I want to interpolate this matrix at one specific value of Y, say y, basically reducing the matrix to dimension Z,X.

How do I do that efficiently in Matlab?

I want to avoid reshaping the matrix to dimensions ZxXxY and then doing `interp3`

```
interp3(X,Z,Y,reshape(MATRIX,[Z X Y]),X,Z,y)
```

because this seems to be using interpolating among two dimension which I do not really need to interpolate. I could do the interpolation (linear) by hand at the point y but I'm sure there is a good way to do this in Matlab.

Comment: So you just want to interpolate based on the y component? Basically you have to find the `y0` for which `y0<=y<y0+1`, then do `squeeze(c*MATRIX(:,y0,:)+(1-c)*MATRIX(:,y0+1,:))` where `c=y-y0`. Of course you have to do this with your original, linear dimensions, but that's just a bit of logistics.

Comment: Sorry, `c`<->`1-c` in the above.

Comment: Yes, that would work but then I would have to reshape to a 3-D matrix first, which I want to avoid, because this is an operation I have to repeat many times. Right now I am finding the y0 and then I manually interpolate the 2-D matrix at the right points. It's a bit of logistics, as you said. I just thought there might be an easier way. Feels like this is in a way an interp1.

Comment: Sure, it is `interp1`, just for a bunch of `X,Z` indices at the same time, which should be the fastest manually. And you either have to reshape, *or* work out the logistics, but there won't be an alternative that cherry-pics out the `y` indices for you from the `Z*(X*Y)` linear ones:) It shouldn't hurt that much, `MATRIX(:,y0,:)` is something like `MATRIX_lin(:,1:X+(y0-1)*X)` or the other way around, depending on how you constructed the `X*Y`-sized dimension.

Comment: Note that using what I'm saying vs `interp3` is not just a matter of convenience and efficiency: in the above case you interpolate a full plane of a data cube, then work with that, while with `interp3` you'd individually interpolate the new data points, considering near neighbours (for instance with trilinear interpolation). I'd be surprised if they gave the same result.